# Ubuntu One sharing structure for multiple users

Tags: ubuntu-one

I wish to implement Ubuntu One for a small office.

Each user will have a small set of personal files ( documents, pictures etc.), and also read/write access to a larger set of common files. Some users have multiple computers, android phones & tablets.

The personal and common files should be synced across all of an individual's devices and also with a file server which is used for backups and other processing.

I have set up accounts for each user aa@domain, bb@domain, etc and have set up a central account office@domain for the file server.

- Personal sharing for each user across devices is working perfectly.
- For the common files - I placed them in the Ubuntu One folder on the file server and shared 'MyStorage' view/change from office@ to each of the users. This worked on the users computers as they appear under 'shared with me' but I cannot see the shared files on the android client
- For sharing the personal files with the file server for backups I have to share each synced folder individually e.g. ~/documents from aa@ to office@. **I cannot see a way of sharing all personal folders.** I cannot share 'MyStorage' from the user as the personal folders are marked as synced.

**Is this the correct structure to follow anyway?**

Answer (score 1):

The Android client does not currently support access to folders shared with the user since the REST API it is using doesn't currently expose them.

If you would like to track the progress of this feature, I would suggest subscribing to the following bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/+bug/810992

Comment: To work around this feature I am going to have the common files 'owned' by the user with the android phone then shared with the other users and file server. This solution only works for one user - but they are the manager!

Comment: Well, we will add the feature to the Android client at some point.  Hopefully your workaround will serve until then though.